# Problemas de alineación en el profile

Tags: bug, perfil

El perfile de usuario tiene algunos problemas relacionados con la internacionalización del sitio.

Como las mismas palabras en español son más largas, aparecen estos problemas.

Lo que esta pasando es que algunas frases/párrafos que en la versión en Inglés ocupan una sola línea, en nuestro sitio ocupan 2. Esto expande los cuadros que las contienen y se rompe el layout original.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los recuadros de reputación y el de impacto ya están arreglados. Los de las publicaciones principales siguen igual. ¿Alguna sugerencia para los devs de cómo podrían arreglar esto?