# Problema alineación en detalles de privilegios

Tags: bug, perfil

Algunos problemas de alineación que vi en el perfil debidos a la internacionalización del sitio

*1:*

[image: Alineación de seguimiento de privilegios 1]

*2:*

[image: Alineación de seguimiento de privilegios 2]

Nota: Los problemas de alineación mencionados [aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/33/problemas-de-alineacion-en-el-profile) son diferentes, no es post duplicado

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problemas de alineacion en el profile](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33/problemas-de-alineacion-en-el-profile)

Comment: @rnrneverdies los problemas aquí mencionados son diferentes a los del duplicado que dices

Comment: Ok Jhon, pero se pierde el hilo si abres otra pregunta sobre el mismo tema, para mi lo mejor seria que edites la pregunta o agregues una respuesta con la nueva información.